# how to undo unsuccessful package upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I regularly update my system with "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade". It usually works fine. But once upon a time I got a buggy update to Network Manager. I could not connect to network, and had to re-install the system. Is there any easier way to fix broken system in such a situation? Any way to roll-back an upgrade, preferably without network connection?

Comment: You may want to consider using btrfs along with apt-btrfs-snapshot in the future instead of ext4. Although, I do believe it's not recommended for production.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible using `apt` or `apt-get`, because you don't have this version offline anymore, but you can do this by downloading older version in .deb package and installing it by `dpkg -i filename.deb`.