# Samba on Ubuntu 20.04 stopped working after todays update: more info

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

Check smbd.

```
smbd --version
Version 4.13.14-Ubuntu
```

Below `smb.conf` was working prior to today's update.
from:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

towards top of file:

```
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = CES
   client min protocol = NT1
# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

Bottom of file:

```
[Samba_Share_Private]
local master = yes
preferred master = yes
# comment needs username and password to access
path = /home/u23_admin/Samba_Share
browseable = yes
quest ok = no
writable = yes
valid users = @samba
```

What's wrong with this for version 4.13.14?

If not `smb.conf` maybe something else.

Comment: When you say “not working”, can I assume you’re seeing an error? If so what is that error? Is there anything in the log files? 

Comment: If you can clearly and reliably demonstrate that an update was responsible, then it's a *reversion* (a bug), and should be reported to the bug tracker. Please edit your question to show us the old and new version numbers of the affected package(s) located in /var/log/apt/history.log. You can just copy/paste the whole relevant line into your question.

Comment: It's probably because they've finally removed SMB1 support. Can you get to your shares if you use Files (Nautilus) "Other Locations"/"Connect to Server" with smb://share.location/folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to undo unsuccessful package upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793563/how-to-undo-unsuccessful-package-upgrade) and [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/)

Answer (score 0):

For any others that come across this, I had this issue today.

After some troubleshooting, my issue turned out to be calling a network interface that was down/had no IP allocated. I recently had issues on my 10gb NIC and fell back to the 1gb port, which apparently caused smbd to core dump when the old NIC was specified for the `interfaces` option in smb.conf.

The following was helpful in troubleshooting, notice the warning:

```
sudo smbd --log-stdout -F

Failed to create /var/log/samba/cores for user 0 with mode 0700
Unable to setup corepath for smbd: File exists
smbd version 4.13.17-Ubuntu started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2020
WARNING: no network interfaces found
daemon_ready: daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
open_sockets_smbd: No sockets available to bind to.
```